# How to separate a JSON string into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a column with strings in dictionary format, like this:

`{'district': 'Ilha do Retiro', 'city': 'RECIFE', 'state': 'PE', 'country': 'BR', 'latitude': -8.062004, 'longitude': -34.908081, 'timezone': 'Etc/GMT+3', 'zipCode': '50830000', 'streetName': 'Avenida Engenheiro Abdias de Carvalho', 'streetNumber': '365'}`

I want to create one column for each key, filled with the value for each row.

I tried using separate with regex:

```
separate(data, address, into = c('district', 'city', 'state', 'country',
                                   'latitude', 'longitude', 'timezone',
                                   'zipCode', 'streetName', 'streetNumber'), 
         "/:.*?/,")
```

However this is not working, and perhaps using separate with regex is not even the best course of action for this. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is effectively JSON (though with single-quotes instead of the requisite double-quotes), we can use `jsonlite`:

```r
txt <- "{'district': 'Ilha do Retiro', 'city': 'RECIFE', 'state': 'PE', 'country': 'BR', 'latitude': -8.062004, 'longitude': -34.908081, 'timezone': 'Etc/GMT+3', 'zipCode': '50830000', 'streetName': 'Avenida Engenheiro Abdias de Carvalho', 'streetNumber': '365'}"
as.data.frame(jsonlite::parse_json(gsub("'", '"', txt)))
#         district   city state country  latitude longitude  timezone  zipCode                            streetName streetNumber
# 1 Ilha do Retiro RECIFE    PE      BR -8.062004 -34.90808 Etc/GMT+3 50830000 Avenida Engenheiro Abdias de Carvalho          365
```